# Maximal determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $1$ to $n^2$

Tags: matrices, permutations, determinant

Given an $n \times n$ matrix whose entries contain $1$ to $n^2$, how can they be arranged to maximize its determinant?  No two entries are the same.

Is there a quick method to do this or is it left to brute force computations?

Comment: Mostly brute force. See: https://oeis.org/A085000

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806100/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-determinant-of-3-times-3-magic-square for $n=3$.